# Difficulty using Ant Design components in react with asp.net core web app (react-redux based)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I am trying to use antd components in react app, I've created an Asp.net Core web app in VS2017, as VS creates react-redux infrastructure I installed antd simply by `npm install antd --save` command.

Before antd I was using react-bootstrap and other libraries so I expected to use antd in the same fashion but got below errors.
can someone enlight me what's wrong here?

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:10:38 
    TS1005: '=' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:12:46 
    TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:12:75 
    TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:12:99 
    TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:54 
    TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:78 
    TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:81 
    TS1109: Expression expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:97 
    TS1109: Expression expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:122 
    TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:130 
    TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:138 
    TS1005: ',' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:27:48 
    TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:27:49 
    TS1109: Expression expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:27:50 
    TS1109: Expression expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:27:68 
    TS1005: '(' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:27:69 
    TS1005: ')' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:29:30 
    TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:29:54 
    TS1005: ';' expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:29:57 
    TS1109: Expression expected.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:10:31 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'unique'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:12:54 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:12:83 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:12:107 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:62 
    TS2693: 'Validator' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:72 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'infer'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:78 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:83 
    TS2693: 'IsOptional' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:94 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:112 
    TS2693: 'never' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:120 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'K'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:124 
    TS2693: 'never' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:132 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'keyof'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:14:138 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'V'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:15:31 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:24:27 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:27:52 
    TS2693: 'Validator' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:27:62 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:27:64 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'K'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:29:38 
    TS2693: 'Validator' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:29:48 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'infer'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:29:54 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:29:59 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'T'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:31:31 
    TS2344: Type 'RequiredKeys<V>' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof V'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:46:78 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'NonNullable'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/@types/prop-types/index.d.ts:50:75 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Required'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/_util/type.d.ts:1:58 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Exclude'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/badge/ScrollNumber.d.ts:27:56 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'DetailedReactHTMLElement'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/badge/ScrollNumber.d.ts:37:52 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'DetailedReactHTMLElement'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/badge/ScrollNumber.d.ts:47:43 
    TS2707: Generic type 'Component<P, S>' requires between 0 and 2 type arguments.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/button.d.ts:26:29 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'AnchorHTMLAttributes'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/button/button.d.ts:30:29 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ButtonHTMLAttributes'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/form/Form.d.ts:17:42 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'FormHTMLAttributes'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/form/FormItem.d.ts:30:103 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ReactNodeArray'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/form/FormItem.d.ts:30:126 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ReactPortal'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/form/FormItem.d.ts:32:102 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ReactNodeArray'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/form/FormItem.d.ts:32:125 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'ReactPortal'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/input-number/index.d.ts:4:54 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'InputHTMLAttributes'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/input/Input.d.ts:7:48 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'InputHTMLAttributes'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/input/TextArea.d.ts:6:47 
    TS2694: Namespace 'React' has no exported member 'TextareaHTMLAttributes'.
ERROR in [at-loader] ./node_modules/antd/lib/skeleton/index.d.ts:15:15 
    TS2415: Class 'Skeleton' incorrectly extends base class 'Component<SkeletonProps, any>'.
  Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
    Type '() => {} | null | undefined' is not assignable to type '() => false | Element | null'.
      Type '{} | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'false | Element | null'.
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update typescript and node modules to latest version.

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
npm udpate
```

This resolved my problem.